# Data format on the wire of AJAX Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

In my AJAX post call, I want the data to be formatted like this (when viewed in Chrome Network Headers details) - which is what the server side is expecting.  The question is: how can I update the JS below to format the data like this:

```
percentages[0].Id:7
percentages[0].Percentage:26.1
percentages[1].Id:8
percentages[1].Percentage:20.3
```

but, the data is currently formatted like this

```
percentages[0][Id]:7
percentages[0][Percentage]:26.1
percentages[1][Id]:8
percentages[1][Percentage]:20.3
```

I am currently formatting the data like this in JS before I send it via AJAX

```
var params = {};
var dict = [];
for (var idx in data) {
    var item = {
        Id: idx,
        Percentage: data[idx]
    };
    dict.push(item);
}
params['percentages'] = dict;
```

where the `data` variable has data like this (when written to Chrome console):

```
Object {7: "26.1", 8: "20.3"}
```

Thanks in advance

Edit:
in response to @Bogangles request: I am using .NET and the structure I'm trying to fill is:

```
IEnumerable<PercentageViewModel> percentages
```

where `PercentageViewModel` is:

```
public class PercentageViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is here. Can you give an example of the data you want from the server language's point of view?

Comment: I think is is only a matter how it is formatted in the console. Semantically there is no difference between those both. You should look at "real" traffic (Network tab, something like 'show raw')

Comment: Ahh, you don't communicate with JSON objects, but use www-form-urlencoded, right?

Comment: the Content-Type of the request is: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer that allow the server side data structure to be populated properly

```
var i = 0;
for (var idx in data) {
    params['percentages[' + i + '].Id'] = data[idx].Id;
    params['percentages[' + i + '].Percentage'] = data[idx].Percentage;
    i++;
}
```