# Controller Action parameter not properly populated from AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm performing an AJAX call and I want the Controller Action (using HttpPost) to accept a parameter of `IEnumerable<PercentageViewModel> percentages`

where `PercentageViewModel` is:

```
public class PercentageViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

The populated data structure on the Action has 2 items in the collection but each item is filled with default values (0 and null).  Here is the data as it appears in Chrome Network Headers - when I click on the AJAX Post XHR call

```
percentages[0][Id]:7
percentages[0][Percentage]:26.1
percentages[1][Id]:8
percentages[1][Percentage]:20.3
```

Here is the JS where I am populating the `params` variable that will be sent using the AJAX Post call.

```
var params = {};
var dict = [];
for (var idx in data) {
    var item = {
        Id: idx,
        Percentage: data[idx]
    };
    dict.push(item);
}
params['percentages'] = dict;
```

where the data variable has data like this (when written to Chrome console):

```
Object {7: "26.1", 8: "20.3"}
```

How can I construct the data in JS so the data structure in the Action is populated properly?

Full disclosure: this is a rephrasing of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989781/data-format-on-the-wire-of-ajax-post) I asked yesterday - just as a more targeted question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer that allow the server side data structure to be populated properly

```
var i = 0;
for (var idx in data) {
    params['percentages[' + i + '].Id'] = data[idx].Id;
    params['percentages[' + i + '].Percentage'] = data[idx].Percentage;
    i++;
}
```